# jquery mobile going back to previous page becomes blank for seconds

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile

From page1, ajax load page2, then change to page2, slide effect works fine.

```
$(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("change",  "#page2", {transition : "slide"} );
```

From page2, ajax loads page3, then change to page3, slide effect works fine.
From page3, `call $.mobile.back();` slide back to page2, works fine.

However from page2,   `call $.mobile.back();`  the screen will become blank for about 1 or 2 seconds, before going back to the page1. (There is no slide effect).

Any idea? thanks.

Comment: From debugging in chrome, From page3, calling $.mobile.back() will slide immediately back to page2. But from page2,  calling $.mobile.back()  will make screen blank until all javascript have completed running.

Comment: If I add $(#page2).remove(); to remove it from DOM, the screen will become blank for a longer time.

Comment: I like to destroy the page2, bring back the page1 quickly. any thought? thanks.